# I used plotpoints=1000 for my Pstricks code but not processing. Hepl me! Thanks

Tags: pstricks, pst-func

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks} % required package
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-func,pst-plot,pst-eucl,pstricks-add,pst-node,multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % required package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\rA=0.2+1,\rB=1+1,\nC=0+10}{10}{\pstVerb{ /a2 \rA\space def /b2 \rB\space def }
\psplotImp[plotpoints=1000,linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red!\nC](-5,-5)(5,5){  y 4 exp a2 y dup mul mul sub x 4 exp sub b2 x dup mul mul add }
\psplotImp[plotpoints=1000,linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue!\nC](-5,-5)(5,5){  y 4 exp b2 y dup mul mul sub x 4 exp sub a2 x dup mul mul add }}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On my updated TeXLive2018 distribution your code compiles without problems when using `xelatex`. What precisely do you mean by "my pstricks code is not processing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the value for `stepfactor`, it is preset to `0.67`

```
[...]
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{stepFactor=0.3}%    <<<======
\multido{\rA=0.2+1,\rB=1+1,\nC=0+10}{10}{\pstVerb{ /a2 \rA\space def /b2 \rB\space def }
[...]
```

[image]